# Sum of the square harmonic series

Tags: analysis

I stumbled across the following series reviewing some HW from a few years ago

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{j=i}^{n}\frac{1}{j}\right)^2$
i.e.
$(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n})^2+(\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n})^2+\ldots+(\frac{1}{n})^2$

This series equals $2n-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$, which I have confirmed with some code.  I am curious if anyone can give a hand in trying to show this relation.  So far, writing $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$ as $S_n$, I have rewritten the sum as

$S_n^2+(S_n-S_1)^2+(S_n-S_2)^2+\ldots +(S_n-S_{n-1})^2$

But have been stuck at dead ends using this approach.  Any thoughts or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you call $S_n$ [is normally denoted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_n$.

Comment: If you expand the squares this becomes almost obvious. There are two kinds of summands: $$\frac{1}{k^2}$$ with $1 \le k \le n$ or $$\frac{2}{kh}$$ with $1 \le k < h \le n$. Now count how many times these summands appear, and you are done.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Do you really mean "Converges?"

Answer (score 2):

We want to evaluate the triple sum
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j, k = i}^{n} \frac{1}{jk}
=
\sum_{j, k = 1}^{n} \frac{\min\{j,\,k\}}{jk}.
$$
We can proceed inductively. If $n=0$, this is $0=\left.2n-S_n\right|_{n=0}$. If we increment from $n=m$ to $n=m+1$, the sum needs to increase by $(2m+1)/(m+1)$. Indeed it increases by$$\sum_{j=1}^{m+1}\frac{1}{m+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\frac{1}{m+1}-\frac{1}{m+1},$$where the last term prevents double-counting of the new case $j=k=m+1$.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $j$ and $k$ between $i$ and $n$ in the first sum, or should one treat the comma as a separator between two different conditions?

Comment: Also, how does this sum connect to the first sum in question?

Comment: @aahlback $j,\,k$ have the same bounds. All I did was change the summation order to reduce to a double sum.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by induction. For $n = 1$ it is easy to show that this holds. Assume the induction hypothesis for some $n$. Then we want to show that
$$
\sum_{p = 1}^{n + 1} \biggl( \sum_{q = p}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{q} \biggr)^2
\;=\;
2 (n + 1) - \sum_{p = 1}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{p}
\text{.}
$$
We have
$$
\biggl( \sum_{q = p}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{q} \biggr)^2
\;=\;
\biggl( \sum_{q = p}^{n} \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{n + 1}\biggr)^2
\;=\;
\biggl( \sum_{q = p}^{n} \frac{1}{q} \biggr)^2 + \frac{2}{n + 1} \sum_{q = p}^{n} \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}
$$
and so
$$
\sum_{p = 1}^{n + 1} \biggl( \sum_{q = p}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{q} \biggr)^2
\;=\;
\sum_{p = 1}^{n} \biggl( \sum_{q = p}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{q} \biggr)^2
+
\frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}
\;=\;
\sum_{p = 1}^{n} \biggl( \sum_{q = p}^{n} \frac{1}{q} \biggr)^2
+
\frac{2}{n + 1} \sum_{p = 1}^n \sum_{q = p}^n \frac{1}{q}
+
\frac{1}{n + 1}
.
$$
Here the last double sum equals
$$
\sum_{p = 1}^n \sum_{q = p}^n \frac{1}{q}
\;=\;
\sum_{q = 1}^n \sum_{p = 1}^q \frac{1}{q}
\;=\;
\sum_{q = 1}^n 1
\;=\;
n.
$$
Now using our assumption, we find
$$
\sum_{p = 1}^{n + 1} \biggl( \sum_{q = p}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{q} \biggr)^2
\;=\;
\sum_{p = 1}^{n} \biggl( \sum_{q = p}^{n} \frac{1}{q} \biggr)^2
+
2
-
\frac{1}{n + 1}
\;=\;
2 n + 2
-
\sum_{p = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{p}
-
\frac{1}{n + 1}
$$
which equals what we wanted to show.